# How to handle Retrieval arguments type mismatch error?

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

Retrieve function when called with wrong parameter type shows error message. The error message does not show which DDDW, datawindow control or dataobject was not retrieved. The ugly error message show no sign of any datawindow control i can go check immediately. I have to go through code. Is there any way i can see (at runtime ) what datawindow control or DDDW causing error?

[image]

PowerBUilder 12.5

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on my Windows 10 PC whenever we add/modify 2nd retrieval argument.
Try killing TeamViewer Services if you have installed TeamViewer on your PC

Reference https://answers.sap.com/questions/10417255/dw-2nd-retrieval-argument-add-fails.html

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to follow the steps that you take to end up in this situation: which is open, and what causes that problem to appear.  This can be done by following the various objects in PB. Personnally, I start from the menu to see what window(s) are opened from there.

Once you know the object that fires that message, use the `search`possibility that you find by right clicking on the object (in the worst case, right click on the library or target) to search over all objects.  This will give you a list of all places where `retrieve`is used.

[image]

Another possibility is to use the `retrievestart` event in datawindow control to code something (messagebox or some kind of logging). That event is fired everytime the method `retrieve` is used for the specific datawindow control.  This is especially interesting if several (or all) your windows inherit from a common ancestor.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using uo as DW control but retrievestart event does not work because of parameter type mismatch error. I have many DW controls in the window i am trying to remove the error. i can search retrieve which returns many lines where retrieve is found and i see no other way